# Не очищаются все таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть БД test1, в ней таблица table1

Я пишу `TRUNCATE test1`

И почему мне пишет Table 'test1.test1' doesn't exist?

Если написать `TRUNCATE table1` то таблица table1 очиститься, но другие же таблицы не очистяться, а пишут, то что TRUNCATE очищает все таблицы у базы

тут наверно придётся сначала вывести все названия таблиц, с помощью php и циклом все удалить?

Comment: TRUNCATE — в языках, подобных SQL, DDL-операция **очистки всех строк в таблице**.

Comment: где это интересно пишут, что очищает все таблицы базы?